# can't install iOS 4.3 Simulator in Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, xcode4.3, ios4

I'm new in iPhone, I installed Xcode 4.3 and now I'm trying to install the iOS 4.3 Simulator from Downloads, it shows the installation progress then give me the following message:

> You can't Save the file "Developer" because the volume "Xcode" is out of Space.

Consider that I was installed old version of Xcode.

Any Help? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you actually install Xcode, or are you running it out of the DMG?

Comment: first time I installed it and watch the installed screens, Now I think that I running it out of DMG because I see the finder that Contains Xcode.app, Sorry I'm new in Mac OS.

Comment: Do you have an Xcode item in your /Applications folder?

Comment: No, I haven't. last time I was opening it from /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app, but now I can't find this /Application Folder in /Developer

Comment: Xcode 4 is now installed in /Applications and the /Developer folder is no longer used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you haven't installed Xcode and that you're running it from the dmg file.

You need to find the dmg from where you are running Xcode - Spotlight will help with this, but it's likely to be in your downloads - and drag it from there to your Applications folder.